# How do I delete a hard link?

Tags: delete

Recently I created a link with the following:

```
sudo ln -n originalFileLocation
```

How do I delete a hard link?

Comment: FYI: `ln -n /path/to/file` creates a file named `file` in the current directory and is shorthand for `ln --no-dereference /path/to/file`. This means that if `/path/to/file` is a symbolic link, the newly created hardlink will point to that symlink instead of the target of the symlink.

Comment: Clarification required.  If <originalFileLocation> is not a symbolic link, then `rm <resulting hardlink>` will delete the inode referenced by <originalFileLocation>, which also results in delisting all the directory entries referencing that inode, including <originalFileLocation>.  Use `unlink` to only remove the directory entry <resulting hardlink>.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can delete it with `rm` as usual: `rm NameOfFile`. Note that with hard links there is no distinction between "the original file" and "the link to the file": you just have two names for the same file, and deleting just one of the names will not delete the other.

Comment: Also ote you will need to rm it as root (use `sudo`), if you created it with the command you provided (as super-user).

Comment: @RafałCieślak: Wrong. All hard-links to an inode share the same access permissions, that of the inode. To delete, i. e. “unlink”, a directory entry of a file you need write permissions on the inode of that file and on the directory that contains the entry that you want to delete. Therefore it's irrelevant which privileges were used to create the hard-link. They may just happen to (still) be the same as at the time of creation.

Comment: Yes, misleading. I see that the idea is that rm removes the name only and the file is only removed once there is no name pointing to it, but still it is misleading. At first, it suggests that there is no way to unlink without deleting the file as well, but I just did it with "unlink <name of link to the file>".  Simpler conceptually to do unlink.

Comment: @CraigHicks What do you mean by "The answer is only correct if..."? What will `rm`ing a hard link do that's incorrect?

Comment: @DanielKaplan - My comment was wrong and I have deleted it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Actually `rm` doesn't work:

```
[user@localhost Products]$ rm AZP/
rm: cannot remove `AZP/': Is a directory
[user@localhost Products]$ rm -r AZP/
rm: cannot remove `AZP': Not a directory
```

What works is `unlink AZP`.

Comment: Are you sure yours was a hard link? Hard links are just like files iirc.

Comment: @Seth, actually I don't remember what was that, but it doesn't want to remove as you could see. Somebody told me to use unlink and it worked. :)

Comment: That's probably because AZP was a file, not a directory, but I couldn't be sure without more information. Unlink should always work though, so no problems there.

Comment: `AZP/` looks like a directory, rm doesn't operate on directories without the recursive flag. Also according to the coreutills docs. >>> Most systems prohibit making a hard link to a directory; on those where
it is allowed, only the super-user can do so (and with caution, since
creating a cycle will cause problems to many other utilities).

Comment: Hard-links to directories are prohibited. If `AZP` is a symbolic link to a directory (or anything else) `rm AZP/` will not work because `rm` thinks its a directory (because of the `/` at the end). However `rm AZP` will work just fine. -1

Answer (score 2):

I have this script to remove redundant hard links. 
But take care - it is quite dangerous.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo Reduce redundant hardlinks in the current folder
echo ------------------------------------------------
echo 
echo "  $(basename $0) [-R]"
echo "      -R means recursive"
echo 
read -p "You can break by pressing Ctrl+C"
echo
ask=1
if [ a$1 == "a-R" ]; then  recursive=" -R "; fi

for i in $(ls -i $recursive | awk '{print $1}' | uniq --repeated | sort); 
do 
    echo "Inode with multiple hardlinked files: $i"
    first=1
    for foundfile in $(find . -xdev -inum $i);
    do 
        if [ $first == 1 ]; then
            echo "  preserving the first file:  $foundfile"
            first=0
        else
            echo "  deleting the redundant file:    $foundfile"  
            #rm $foundfile  
        fi
    done 
    if [ $ask == 1 ]; then 
        read -p "Delete all the rest of redundant hardlinks without asking? y/N "
        if [ a${REPLY,,} == "ay" ]; then  ask=0; fi
    fi  
#   read -p "pause for sure"
    echo
done
echo "All redundant hardlins are removed."
echo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove only the link and thus keep the original file, you have to use unlink.

Comment: Have you read what [`unlink(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/unlink.1.html) does? It's a shallow wrapper around the [`unlink(2)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man2/unlink.2.html) system call, the same system call that [`rm(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/rm.1.html) uses for all files that aren't directories.

Comment: This answer is misleading. With hardlinked files there's no distinction between "link" and "original file"; all hardlinks refer to the same file/content/inode, represented by different directory entries. `unlink`, despite it's name, will not separate a hardlinked into two separate files, but remove the "unlinked" directory entry (but not the file/content/inode, as long as the link count is > 1).